# N th term of series:0,1,3,6,10,15,21,

Tags: algorithm, time, series, rational-numbers

0,1,3,6,10,15,21,...
each term gets incremented in the order of natural numbers
I tried to generate the nth of the series but ended with TLE
here's my code

```
s=0
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    s=s+(i-1);
```

Can any anybody help me with a better algorithm.

Comment: Hint: The Nth term in the series can be calculated directly, without any looping whatsoever.  In fact, Googling the series will take you to a wikipedia page about the series that gives the exact equation for doing this.

Comment: Searching [specifically on OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C6%2C10&language=english&go=Search) is useful for identifying well-known integer sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Think the problem as solving recurrence of the form

T(n) = T(n-1) + n
given T(0)=0

T(1) = T(0) + 1

T(2) = T(1) + 2

on solving recurrence you are going to obtain T(n) = n*(n+1)/2

Answer (score 1):

This series, gives for `n` the sum of the natural number from `0` to `n`. There is a [simple formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) for calculating this `(n * (n+1)) / 2`.